# Rails FactoryGirl Duplicated Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factories defined in my factories.rb file:

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "person-#{n}@example.com" }

    factory :country do
        ...
    end
    factory :state do
        country
        ...
    end
    factory :school do
        name "Test School"
        country
        state
    end
    factory :user do
        school
        email
        ... 
    end
end
```

When testing in rspec calling `FactoryGirl.create(:school)` in one of my descriptors causes two schools with the name "Test School" to be created.

I thought the factories defined in factories.rb were just a bunch of unsaved instance objects, can somebody clarify as to why I'm having this issue?

Here's the exact rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "school login" do
  it "displays a success message upon successful login to school",do  
    school = FactoryGirl.create(:school)
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :username => "jdoe")
    School.all.each do |school|
      puts school.name #2x => "Test School"
    end
    visit school_path(user.school)
    click_link('login')
    fill_in "username", :with => "jdoe"
    fill_in "password", :with => "secret"
    click_button "Sign in"
    expect(page).to have_selector(".alert-success")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line creates the first school

```
school = FactoryGirl.create(:school)
```

and this one the second:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :username => "jdoe")
```

This happens because in your user factory you defined that every user should have a school, so FactoryGirl is creating it for you. If you want your user associated with the first school, you can do something like this:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :username => "jdoe", :school => school)
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the context code? and how did you find there are 2 `schools` created?

the code written in ruby files ( factories ) is neither saved to database nor created as object until you declare `create(:object)` or `build(:object)`.

```
# Returns a User instance that's not saved
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

# Returns a saved User instance
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

for more details, refer to : https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories

Comment: I don't know what "context code" is, but I added the relevant rspec above. Notice I'm outputting every school and their respective names - that's how I'm determining that two schools are created.